# My screws won’t turn in trellidoor frame

Tags: screws

I’m trying to remove an old trellidoor but the screws won’t turn at all. They are not worn down or painted on ( they are screwed into a metal frame)

The drill I’m using is a 18v with new drill bits. Could it be that the drill isn’t powerful enough, they look like normal screws to me!

Any advice would be great before I purchase a drill I don’t need! 
Thanks

Comment: What screws? Either describe the situation better or post a link to a photo, please.

Comment: you do not use drill bits to turn screws, you use screwdriver bits ..... `Any advice would be great before I purchase a drill I don’t need!` .... that is obvious,  get a regular screwdriver

Comment: Steel screws into aluminum by any chance? This may be a case where WD40, vicegrips and a nice sharp drill bit may be your friend after the screw head torques off. You're certain it's screws, not pins?

Comment: You do not say if the screws are simply spinning or if your bit just spins in the screw heads. If the screws are spinning the sheet metal is stripped and they are held in place by magic if you will.. in other words you will need to get a small tool to get under the head and apply pressure outward while at the same time turning the screw to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for starting with the obvious, if the business end of your drill looks like this

[image: drill with screwdriver mode switch highlighted]

Make sure the arrow lines up with the icon of a screw, not the drill or hammer. You want the drill in screwdriver mode.

Also check the number, this sets the clutch that prevents you driving screws too deep. 1 is the weakest. Turn it up to a higher number if the clutch is clicking and the screw is not turning.

[image: drill with clutch settings highlighted]

Sometimes it can be better to get started with hand tools

[image: three screwdrivers]

You can sometimes exert more force with a hand screwdriver than with a drill in driver mode. (Though this might not apply if you have an 18v impact driver, not just a hammer-action or combi drill).

Some screwdrivers let you use a wrench (spanner) on them to increase the turning force. You need to also provide a lot more axial force along the length of the screwdriver to prevent it slipping out of proper contact with the screw.

[image: screwdriver with spanner on shaft]

Note that you need to ensure the driver bit is an exact fit for the screw. In my example note the difference between the Philips and Pozidriv screwdrivers, use the correct one that matches the screw. For slotted screws it is very important that the screwdriver tip fills the slot tightly from side to side and end to end.

[image: Screwdriver tips]

If all else fails you can try a manual impact driver.

[image: manual impact driver]

Which are used in conjunction with these

[image: club hammer and claw hammer]

But frankly, if you get that far, chances of success may be small.

---

It may help to do any of

- Apply a penetrating lubricant and leave for an hour.
- Heat a metal screw that is in in a metal frame.